# How to get Objects ID

Tags: django

I am trying to get the ID of Options however I do not now what I can do to get it?

I am new to Django - I have got the question ID through a parameter however I am not trying to pass another parameter. Is there a filter or get command that can be used?

I am trying to edit an existing option however it doesn't know which option it is looking for as there is more than one. The only way to identify is through its ID

Model

```
class Option(models.Model):
    OptionID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    OptionText = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    QuestionsID = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.OptionID)
```

View

```
@login_required(login_url='loginPage')
def question_editOption(request, id):
    question = Question.objects.get(QuestionsID = id)
    options = Option.objects.filter(QuestionsID = question)
    current_user = request.user
    c = current_user.userID
    if current_user.is_admin:

        if request.method == 'POST':
            edited = request.POST.get('Q')
            if request.POST['Q']:
                obj = Option.objects.filter(QuestionsID = id, ).update(OptionText = edited)
                messages.success(request, "Edited")
                return redirect('dashboardAdmin')
            # elif not request.POST['Q']:
            #     obj = Question.objects.filter(QuestionsID = id).update(QuestionText = oldVal)
            #     messages.error("Question Is Null!")

            #     return redirect('question/edit/<int:id>/')

    
    else:
        messages.error("User is not admin")
        return redirect('dashboardPage')
    context = {'question' : question,
            'options' : options}
    return render(request, 'editOption.html', context)
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        
    <head>
        <title>Admin Panel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    
        <style>
            body,
            html {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
                background: #7abecc !important;
            }
            .user_card {
                width: 350px;
                margin-top: auto;
                margin-bottom: auto;
                background: #74cfbf;
                position: relative;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                flex-direction: column;
                padding: 10px;
                box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
                border-radius: 5px;
    
            }
    
            .form_container {
                margin-top: 20px;
            }
    
            #form-title{
                color: #fff;
                
            }

            #questionTitle {
                text-align: left;
            }
    
            .login_btn {
                width: 100%;
                background: #33ccff !important;
                color: white !important;
            }
            .login_btn:focus {
                box-shadow: none !important;
                outline: 0px !important;
            }
            .login_container {
                padding: 0 2rem;
            }
            .input-group-text {
                background: #f7ba5b !important;
                color: white !important;
                border: 0 !important;
                border-radius: 0.25rem 0 0 0.25rem !important;
            }
            .input_user,
            .input_pass:focus {
                box-shadow: none !important;
                outline: 0px !important;
            }
    
            #messages{
                background-color: grey;
                color: #fff;
                padding: 10px;
                margin-top: 10px;
            }


        </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container h-100">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
                <div class="user_card">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    
    
                        <h3 id="form-title">Edit Option</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">
                        <form method="POST" action="">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="text" id="{{ options.OptionText }}" name="Q" value="{{ options.OptionText  }}">
    
                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
                                     <input class="btn login_btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
                                   </div>
                        </form>
    
                    </div>
                    {% for message in messages %}
                        <p id='messages'>{{message}} </p>
                    {%  endfor  %}
            
                
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: You need to define another input in your form specifiying option_id

Answer (score 0):

```
def question_editOption(request, id):
    question = Question.objects.get(QuestionsID = id)
    options = Option.objects.filter(QuestionsID = question[0])
```

Without the error message I'm not 100% sure what the fix will be.

But when I define an object and passing it through as the pk for another field I usually have to actually access the object by accessing the first index being [0]

I assume the id in your function is the primary key being passed from the URL?

Comment: wouldnt this just get first option? i am trying to get a specific option

Comment: The question ID would be unquie right? So it should only return one object. Once you access the object you can access the fields of that object.